# Using "category id" in "discover/explore" entrypoint to narrow down results

Tags: here-api

I want to get a list of "Children's museum" at Santa Cruz.

Using the below query, am able to get the list of ALL museums and landmarks at Santa Cruz:
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=36.97425%2C-122.03099&cat=sights-museums&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5&app_id=my-app-id&app_code=my-app-code

How can I use the **"Category ID: 300-3100-0027     Children's Museum"** mentioned in below documentation link **to get only "Children's Museum"**?

Documentation link: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/place_categories/category-300-sights-museums.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set cat=300-3100-0027 with cs=pds:

https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=36.97425%2C-122.03099&cat=300-3100-0027&cs=pds&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5&app_id=yyy&app_code=xxx